# Proof check for $r(IJ)=r(I\cap J)=r(I)\cap r(J)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, commutative-algebra, ideals

Atiyah and Macdonald - Exercise 1.13.iii - Page 9

Let $A$ be a commutative ring. Let $I$ and $J$ be ideals of $A$. We shall denote by $r(I)$ the radical of $I$, where we recall that:
$$r(I)=\{x\in A\mid x^n\in I,n>0\}.$$

> Can you please check my proof below that $r(IJ)=r(I\cap J)=r(I)\cap r(J)$:

$\mathsf{Proof:}$ $IJ\subset IR\subset I$ and $IJ\subset RJ\subset J$, so that $IJ\subset I\cap J$. Then we know that $r(K)\supset K$ for any ideal $K$, so we have that:
$$r(IJ)\subset r(I\cap J)$$
Next, we note that clearly $I\cap J\subset I$ and $I\cap J\subset J$, so that $r(I\cap J)\subset r(I)$ and $r(I\cap J)\subset r(J)$, so that we have:
$$r(IJ)\subset r(I\cap J)\subset r(I)\cap r(J),$$
Finally, we note that if $x\in r(I)\cap r(J)$, then $x^n\in I$ and $x^k\in J$, but that $x^{nk}\in IJ\implies x\in r(IJ)$ and we have:
$$r(IJ)\subset r(I\cap J)\subset r(I)\cap r(J)\subset r(IJ),$$
which completes this argument. $\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\Box$

Comment: It's a quite fine proof for me.

Comment: Nicely done. ${}{}{}$

Comment: It is o.k, well done :)

Answer (score 1):

The community say it is OK in the comments.